# Flutter GetIt Plugin - No type xxx is registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I set everything up as shown in the example project:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:places/services/authService.dart';

final locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerSingleton<AuthService>(AuthService());
  print("registered");
}
```

with the call in the main file

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I have some Check where the locator also correctly return my AuthService

```
class AuthGuardView extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthGuardView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthGuardViewState createState() => _AuthGuardViewState();
}

class _AuthGuardViewState extends State<AuthGuardView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<AuthGuardViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: AuthGuardViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) => model.initialise(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => model.isLoggedIn
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text("Logged In"),
            )
          : SignUpView(),
    );
  }
}


class AuthGuardViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  AuthService _authService = locator<AuthService>();
  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  void initialise() async {
    isLoggedIn = await _authService.isLoggedIn();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

If I do the exact same thing inside the ViewModel for the SignUpView I get the following error

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building SignUpView(dirty, state: _SignUpViewState#01129):
flutter: No type AuthService is registered inside GetIt.
flutter:  Did you forget to pass an instance name?
flutter: (Did you accidentally do  GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;did you
flutter: forget to register it?)
flutter: 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
flutter: Failed assertion: line 248 pos 14: 'instanceFactory != null'
```

In the ViewModel for the AuthGuard I do successfully retrieve the auth service. I also commented out the locator code (because I thought it might be the async call or something like that) but the same error persists.

I am using get_it: ^4.0.1 but the error persists when downgrading to 3.x.x

[image]

Here the SignUpViewModel

```
class SignUpViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  SignUpViewModel(){
    if(locator.isRegistered<AuthService>()) {
      AuthService _authService = locator<AuthService>();
    } 
  }
  var textInputFormatter = [
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'\d')),
    PhoneNumberTextInputFormatter()
  ];
  var textEditingController;
  var context;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting one. Where do you create the view models?
If you give me access to your project I can try it myself.

Comment: I already reverted the changes and switched to a pure provider/change notifier architecture. But all the code is in the question. I create the ViewModels inside the ViewModel.withconsumer() call (under ViewModel) :S I have one project here that (except for not using firebase auth has the same setup (no singletons registered yet so no error) https://github.com/lunaticcoding/MilleSandersApp (the developer branch has what you are looking for)

Comment: if you give me your github handle i can give you access to the correct repo (you have to use an older commit though)

Comment: Handle is escamoteur

Comment: oh my bad. Are you on gitlab too? :O

Comment: I guess I never pushed that code but fixed it right away :S sorry :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest `get_it` version in `pubspec.yaml` ( now it is `get_it: ^4.0.2` ) resolve the issue for me.

Comment: I'm using the same get_it version, but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 13):

This happens when the class to be registered as `singleton` has async methods. To fix this you need to await the singleton to be fully generated before `runApp()` is ran.

```
void main() async {

/*  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() is required in Flutter v1.9.4+ 
 *  before using any plugins if the code is executed before runApp. 
 */
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();


// Configure injecction
   await setupLocator();

   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Indeed, only the line `await setupLocator();` is needed. The old code `Api _api = locator<Api>();` remains untouched

Comment: I awaited the setup function but still have the error

Comment: Do you use code generation or you register your singletons manually? Pls, can I see a link of a screenshot of how you register and called the singletons?

Answer (score 4):

Adding this answer, as I think it might help others!

I have faced the same issue earlier. For me, it was due to an ordering issue. So make sure to initiate/declare the dependency objects first and then instantiate/declare the dependent one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, GetIt was struggling with my import statements. You need to use package imports instead of relative imports for it to work correctly.

Do this:

```
import 'package:mypackage/features/some_file.dart';
```

Instead of:

```
import '../features/some_file.dart';
```

Comment: If you're using injectable package you can also set preferRelativeImports: true so there's no need to change all imports

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced this issue. Nothing made sense. Then I remembered, that I recently did case sensitive renaming.

I changed i.e. `Services/Database/Database.dart` to `services/database/database.dart`, but in one file, I used import with the lowercased version, while in the other, it still was the uppercased version. Making the case consistent throughout the project was the fix I needed.