# FirebaseAuth is not registered inside GetIt. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

When I try to restart my app, it gives: **FirebaseAuth is not registered inside GetIt**. and **'instanceFactory != null**

I also get these errors:

***I/flutter (22720): Error while creating IAuthService
I/flutter (22720): Stack trace:***

***I/flutter (22720): #12     _GetItImplementation.get (
I/flutter (22720): Error while creating SignInCubit
I/flutter (22720): Stack trace:***

When I do debug, after the *create: (context) => getIt() section* it gives this error:
I have @lazySingleton above the cubit...

What should I do? I saw this link ([Flutter GetIt Plugin - No type xxx is registered inside GetIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131822/flutter-getit-plugin-no-type-xxx-is-registered-inside-getit)) on the StackOverflow, and I tried some things, but it did not work.

I call the codes before the runApp like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureDependencies(Environment.dev);
  runApp(const AppWidget());
}
```

my injection.dart (some people called this setupLocator) here:

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
void configureDependencies(env) {
  $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}
```

my abstract class authservice is here:

```
abstract class IAuthService {
  Future<void> signOut();
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password});
}
```

and lastly, my FirebaseAuthService is here:

```
@LazySingleton(as: IAuthService)
class FirebaseAuthService implements IAuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  FirebaseAuthService(this._firebaseAuth);

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      var errorCode = e.code;
      if (errorCode == "auth/wrong-password") {
        return left(const AuthFailure.invalidPassword());
      } else if (errorCode == "auth/user-not-found") {
        return left(const AuthFailure.invalidEmail());
      } else if (errorCode == "auth/user-disabled") {
        return left(const AuthFailure.userDisabled());
      }
    }
    return right(unit);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a rule, which is related with third party libs. we need to add @module above the abstract class (I mean modules for the injectable). After creating this file, run the related method:

```
@module
abstract class InjectableModule {
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseAuth get firebaseAuth => FirebaseAuth.instance;
}
```

> flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs